# Nil? resolve variable returns nil after def

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure so this might be obvious.

```
(println (nil? (resolve 'x)))
(def x 1)
(println (nil? (resolve 'x)))
```

This prints out

```
true
true
```

Why doesn't the second `println` output `false`?

According to the examples on [ClojureDocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/resolve), shouldn't this be the case?

**EDIT:**

I'm **not** running this through REPL.

This is how I got there:

Create a project via `lein new testing`.

After modifications to core.clj, it looks like this:

```
(ns testing.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [& args]

  (println (nil? (resolve 'x)))
  (def x 1)
  (println (nil? (resolve 'x)))
)
```

When ran through `lein run`, output is:

```
true
true
```

Answer (score 0):

When I evaluate those expressions in a Clojure REPL, I get true for the first one, and false for the second one.  How you are you starting the Clojure REPL?  What version of Clojure are you using?  Can you reproduce this consistently?

Comment: I get this by running a project within Leiningen.

Comment: Your updated question uses `def` inside of a function.  While it is not an error to do this, and there are a few debug situations where it can be useful to do, in 'production code' it is very abnormal Clojure code that does this.  Are you asking because you want to know exactly how the Clojure implementation gives this result?  Because if you are asking because you want to write production Clojure code like this, my suggestion would be "don't do that".

Answer (score 0):

`(resolve 'x)` try to get a Var named by (bound to) the `x` symbol. If this Var does not exist, it should return nil. So your assumptions are correct.
If you are coding with a live REPL, remember that code you evaluate stays in memory until you replace it by a new version or manually undefine it.

---

Here is a visual REPL session from my side showing the correct behavior:

[image: Screen recording of a REPL session described in this post]

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange about your environment:

```
~/expr/demo > lein repl
demo.core=> (resolve 'x)
nil
demo.core=> (resolve 'x)
nil
demo.core=> (resolve 'x)
nil
demo.core=> (resolve 'x)
nil
demo.core=> (def x 1)
#'demo.core/x
demo.core=> (resolve 'x)
#'demo.core/x
```

Comment: I'm not running it through REPL even with Leiningen. I run it with `lein run` (see my edits in question).

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following program instead, and read the output carefully.  Note that the doc string for the function 'resolve' says that it resolves the symbol in the namespace that is the current value of *ns*, and that is a "dynamic var", which according to the output of the program shown below, is equal to the 'user' namespace by default, different than the namespace where the function is defined, which is the namespace where 'x' is 'def'd.

```
(ns testing.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [& args]

  (println)
  (println "before (def x 1)")
  (println "*ns*=" *ns*)
  (println "(resolve 'x)=" (resolve 'x))
  (println "(resolve 'user/x)=" (resolve 'user/x))
  (binding [*ns* 'testing.core]
    (println "*ns*=" *ns*)
    (println "(resolve 'x)=" (resolve 'x))
    (println "(resolve 'user/x)=" (resolve 'user/x)))

  (def x 1)
  (println)
  (println "after (def x 1)")
  (println "*ns*=" *ns*)
  (println "(resolve 'x)=" (resolve 'x))
  (println "(resolve 'user/x)=" (resolve 'user/x))
  (binding [*ns* 'testing.core]
    (println "*ns*=" *ns*)
    (println "(resolve 'x)=" (resolve 'x))
    (println "(resolve 'user/x)=" (resolve 'user/x))))
```

Output on my system:

```
before (def x 1)
*ns*= #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x524f3b3a user]
(resolve 'x)= nil
(resolve 'user/x)= nil
*ns*= testing.core
(resolve 'x)= #'testing.core/x
(resolve 'user/x)= nil

after (def x 1)
*ns*= #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x524f3b3a user]
(resolve 'x)= nil
(resolve 'user/x)= nil
*ns*= testing.core
(resolve 'x)= #'testing.core/x
(resolve 'user/x)= nil
```